# Open liberty features

Tags: open-liberty

I am currently evaluating Kumuluzee vs Wildfly Swarm vs OpenLiberty. I have some questions:

1. Does OpenLiberty have Gradle samples/plugin in addition to the maven one.
2. Is it possible/documented how to extend OL itself with libraries, rather than putting them in web-inf/lib. (Skinny wars ). If possible, are such jars excluded from redeployment scans (faster dev cycles)?
3. In many cases one wants to deploy several wars in single jvm (anti-microservice). Can several  web applications can you enumerate in the server.xml file?

Comment: I would suggest splitting this into several discreet questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MicroProfile Showcase Application has been updated so that you can build with Maven or Gradle.
https://github.com/OpenLiberty/sample-mpconf

Quite a few of the samples in https://github.com/WASdev/ were updated in October to show using Gradle. They do not use the Open Liberty runtime maven coordinates but many of them could.

Comment: Thanks Cindy! Based on your guidance, I closed 2 issues in github for ci.cradle, but did left one open - let's continue the discussion there?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Does OpenLiberty have Gradle samples/plugin in addition to the maven one.

Yes, there are gradle and maven integrations for Liberty:

- Gradle: https://github.com/WASdev/ci.gradle
- Maven: https://github.com/WASdev/ci.maven

> 2. Is it possible/documented how to extend OL itself with libraries, rather than putting them in web-inf/lib. (Skinny wars ). If possible, are such jars excluded from redeployment scans (faster dev cycles)?

Yes, Liberty has a concept of "shared libraries" which can point to a file or folder.  Then, shared libraries can be referenced by applications.  More documentation here: [Shared Libraries](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/cwlp_sharedlibrary.html)

> 3. In many cases one wants to deploy several wars in single jvm (anti-microservice). Can several web applications can you enumerate in the server.xml file?

Yes, you can have as many applications as you want.  There are 2 main ways to add an application to a server.

**Dropin apps:**
You can drop applications into the `${server.config.dir}/dropins/` folder, which doesn't require any additional server configuration.

**Configured apps:**
You can explicitly configure applications in server.xml using the `<application/>` configuration element.  For more details see the [Configuration elements](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.liberty.autogen.core.doc/ae/rwlp_config_application.html) page.

Comment: It seems the Gradle plug-in is targeted to the generic Liberty server, not OpenLiberty? Also, where can one find an example project with OpenLiberty?

Comment: You can use the plugins for both generic Liberty (aka WAS Liberty) and OpenLiberty.  Check out this guide on openliberty.io for an example of using the maven plugin with OpenLiberty: https://openliberty.io/guides/maven-intro.html

Comment: Thanks Andy, I was actually looking for Gradle example .